# Define multiple variables of different types in a for-loop

Tags: octave

I'm new to GNU Octave (earlier made all plots with gnuplot); and now I have to compare 2 data sets, plotting from 2 different files in one figure.

I have something about 100 variables of different types (scalars, matrices, stings), which I define like so, loading from the files:

```
load(file_1);
varX_file_1 = X_values;
varY_file_1 = Y_values;

load(file_2);
varX_file_2 = X_values;
varY_file_2 = Y_values;
```

---

But I'd like to do this stuff in some loop like so (for creating variable names like varX_file_1 and varX_file_2):

```
names = ["varX"; "varY"; "matrixC"; "scalarA"];
cases = [file_1, file_2];
for i = 1:rows(names)
vars1.(names(i,:)) = cases(1);
vars2.(names(i,:)) = cases(1);
endfor
```

And then to fill this created variables names with corresponding variables like so:

```
vars1(i) = file_1(i);
vars2(i) = file_2(i);
```

But unfortunately I have no idea how to build such a loop in octave. I tried it with struct(), but I didn't really understand how struct works.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Use `cases={'file_1','file_2',...};` Then you can do `s=load(cases{1})`, which returns a struct `s` with all the variables. If these files all contain the same variables, you can simply concatenate the many `s` structs within the loop.

Comment: Hi, thanks for a suggestion, I solved the problem by adding a for- and a if- statements as well :)